# Reversing a Number using Class in python

Tags: python

I am writing a program to reverse a Number using class object.I have created constructor which reads kwargs.**The code does not throw an error** but returns 60 instead of 42.

```
class Nups:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self._vars = kwargs
    def rev(self,f):
        h=0
        r=self._vars.get(f)
        print r
        while r!=0:
            h=h+(r%10)*10
            r=r/10
        return h
```

Now `main()`:

```
def main():
    p=Nups(first=24,second=45)
    print p.rev('first')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
24
60
```

Comment: I assume you're using Python 2. If so, it would be better if `Nups` is defined to inherit from `object`, like this: `class Nups(object):`. Also you should be using the floor division operator: `r = r // 10` or `r //= 10`. With these changes, your code will be compatible to both Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
h = h * 10 + (r % 10)
```

instead of

```
h = h + (r % 10) * 10
```

Your code was taking the last digit and multiplying it by `10` and then adding it to `h`. Instead you should multiply `h` by `10` and then add the last digit of the number to `h`

Comment: @PM2Ring Duly noted!

Answer (score 0):

Can do this as well :

```
return eval(str(number)[::-1])
```